# Silently install Apache through Advanced Installer

Tags: apache, silent-installer, advanced-installer

I am trying to silently install apache using [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) 8.9, but it is still prompting me for user interaction even though I pass the command parameters in the Silent (No UI) field.

msiexec /i  "httpd-2.2.22-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi" /qn /passive ALLUSERS=1 SERVERADMIN=admin@localhost SERVERNAME=localhost SERVERDOMAIN=localhost SERVERPORT=80

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameters set in "Silent (No UI)" field are used by the prerequisite only if the bootstrapper is running with silent UI. If you want these parameters to be used for all the UI levels of the bootstrapper you need to set the same command line in all fields, i.e. Full UI, Basic UI and Silent (No UI).

Comment: Hi, I know this question is answered a long time ago, but have one query, you might help me, I've asked one question here and it looks like whatever I am trying to do, that you have already done. Can you please take a look at this question and do help me if you can, thanks in advance. :)
Question URL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949030/steps-to-deploy-web-application-on-tomcat-via-install4j-installer-or-advanced-in

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @bogdan. Also, I noticed that you pass the entire msiexec command into the parameters. If you have specified apache as a prerequisite, you only need to pass the arguments of msiexec in the command parameters, e.g. /qn, /passive etc. You shouldn't pass "msiexec" as command line parameters.