# Steps to deploy web application on Tomcat via install4j installer or Advanced Installer

Tags: java, tomcat, install4j, advanced-installer

Can anyone give me some documentation link/tutorial which could help me create .exe windows installer for Java Web Application.

I have a Java Web Project which runs on tomcat server and I want to run theproject on windows with a single click. So for the same I want to create .exe file which I could use as installer to run on any machine.

I couldn't find any proper document to create .exe file with the use of popular installers like **Install4J** and **Advanced Installer**.

Please let me know if somebody has document or any kind help is highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at Advanced Installer's [Native Java Launcher](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/native-java-launcher.html).  While I have managed to get tomcat to install as a windows service, I have NOT done so in a Java project, so I have no additional insights for you on that front.  You may also want to post on the [Advanced Installer Forums](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/) as it is more conducive to discussion and the folks there tend to be quite good about knowing how to get things working.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'll post into Advanced Installer Forums also.

Comment: Also, before posting, check the threads on Advanced Installer Forums, there are quite a few discussions that can help you integrate Tomcat  http://www.advancedinstaller.com/search.html?cx=006686361644407349086%3Ayneweleowua&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&q=tomcat

Comment: Or you can start directly by creating a project with the Tomcat template, then continue editing it manually as indicated in the tutorial you already know (to add the java launcher EXE). http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/java-project-tab.html

Answer (score 3):

According to my understading of your question, I believe you'd need these few things to do:

- Copying your tomcat containing the WAR file in webapps directory to
  default/specified directory.
- Or else for an existing tomcat, copy your war file in tomcat/webapps
  directory.
- Execute tomcat startup.bat from tomcat/bin.

For the above tasks, I'd say the below links will suffice:
[Install4J](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2010/12/my-first-try-with-install4j-tutorial.html), [Advanced Installer Tutorial](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-java.html)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I already took a look at tutorial that you gave but there I could not find documentation for Tomcat Web Application. Though I'll take a look at it again. Thanks,

Comment: Why are you concerned about the tomcat specifically, all you gotta do is copy a directory and run the bat file.

Comment: In install4j you copy the WAR file with a "Copy files or directories" action.